# No value given for one or more required parameters using datetimepicker

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, datetimepicker

i have a problem in my code. I want to filter between two dates.
Here is my code. I'm using Microsoft Access Database.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From Table2 where TransacDate between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' And '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'", conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; 
}
```

Now, there's an empty row inside my datagridview.

Comment: What is the actual resulting string of the SQL code you're executing?  Are you able to execute it manually on the database?

Comment: Can you put the query into a string first, and show us the content of that string? As in `var debugString = "Select * From Table2 where 
                           Transac_Date between '"+ 
                 dataTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyy") + "' And '" + 
                 dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyy") + "'";`

Comment: Done putting it in a string. @oerkelens

Comment: @dad: Can you also *show us the content of that string*?  If your SQL code is failing, a great first step is to *look at your SQL code*.

Comment: @David i'm using visual studio 2017 so are you referring to look at the configuration wizard first? because the SQL statement is here.

Comment: @dad: No, I'm referring to your variable called `query`.  At runtime that variable holds a string value.  That string value is the actual SQL code you're trying to execute.  What *is* that string value?

Comment: Until you show us the actual query as was asked two days ago, I don't think going on guessing what might be happening is going to help you much...

Comment: i already updated my code, check the code. But now, it displays empty rows.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you refuse to give us the actual content of the sql query? If you want help, show it. Two days ago you were asked about that, but you simply won't answer. How can we smell what is in that string?

Answer (score 2):

I recently made the same mistake with a datetime format.

Try

```
"MM-dd-yyyy"
```

instead of

```
"MM-dd-yyy"
```

Comment: That's my theory, it either takes yy or yyyy.  The yyy may be throwing this off.

Comment: Are you sure it's the datetimepicker it's hanging on?  Try this change, `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn);`  as I believe that always requires a connection to reference.

Comment: what line does it happen on?

Comment: line "da.Fill(ds);"

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Access should be enclosed by `#` octothorpes.

Change your code to:

```
"Select * From Table2 where Transac_Date between #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "# And #" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "#";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear as to what app or front end is generating this sql statement.  It looks nothing like Access syntax.

I would suggest, in Access, using the standard query design view - and build a query that results in the dataset you seek.  Then you can option/put this query into SQL View to see the syntax.